# How to write a loop that cites stata Mata solvenl() function?

Tags: loops, stata

I am working on a grid search program that solves the solution of z1 z2 z3 for many pairs of e and phi. After many attempts, I figure out how to solve the problem for any specific pair e and phi, but cannot figure out how to write a loop to make it work for all the pairs. The following are the whole codes. I very appreciate your help!

The first part sets the values of e and phi, which has no problem.

```
obs 20000
gen id=_n
gen e=.
gen phi=.
gen N_e=100  // number of values for e 
gen N_phi=200 // number of values for phi
gen step_e=0.01 // step of grids for e
gen step_phi=1 // step of grids for phi
gen error_code=.
gen z1=.
gen z2=.
gen z3=.
gen b1=.
gen b2=.
gen b3=.

foreach seq_e of numlist 1(1)100 {
    foreach seq_phi of numlist 1(1)200 {
        qui replace e=0.01*`seq_e'   if id==(`seq_e'-1)*(N_phi)+`seq_phi'
        qui replace phi=`seq_phi'   if id==(`seq_e'-1)*(N_phi)+`seq_phi'

    }
}
```

The second part is where I have problem. The following code works fine for any pair of e and phi. By changing  temp_e=st_data(1, "e") and temp_phi=st_data(1, "phi") to temp_e=st_data(n, "e") and temp_phi=st_data(n, "phi"), I can feed the nth pair of e and phi to the program.

```
clear mata
mata: 

temp_e=st_data(1, "e") 
temp_phi=st_data(1, "phi")

st_local("e", strofreal(temp_e)) 
st_local("phi", strofreal(temp_phi))


void function solvez(real colvector z, real colvector y)
{ 

y[1] = ((20000+z[1])*(1-0.2)/(1+1/`e'))*(1-(20000/(20000+z[1]))^(1+1/`e'))-`phi'-z[1]*(1-0.25)
y[2] = ((9000+z[2])*(1-0.2)/(1+1/`e'))*(1-(9000/(9000+z[2]))^(1+1/`e'))-`phi'-z[2]*(1-0.25)
y[3] = ((35000+z[3])*(1-0.25)/(1+1/`e'))*(1-(35000/(35000+z[3]))^(1+1/`e'))-`phi'-z[3]*(1-0.3)

}
S = solvenl_init()
solvenl_init_evaluator(S, &solvez())
solvenl_init_type(S, "zero")
solvenl_init_technique(S, "newton")
solvenl_init_startingvals(S, J(3,1,10)) 
solvenl_init_conv_maxiter(S, 100) 
solvenl_init_iter_log(S, "off")
_solvenl_solve(S)
ERR=solvenl_result_error_code(S)
M=solvenl_result_values(S)
st_matrix("M", M)
st_matrix("ERR", ERR)
end

matrix list M
matrix list ERR


replace z1=M[1,1] if id==`num'
replace z2=M[2,1] if id==`num'
replace z3=M[3,1] if id==`num' 

replace b1=(e*0.05/(1-0.2)*20000-z1)/50 if id==`num'
replace b2=(e*0.05/(1-0.2)*9000-z2)/50 if id==`num'
replace b3=(e*0.05/(1-0.25)*35000-z3)/500 if id==`num'

replace error_code=ERR[1,1] if id==`num'
```

My problem is how to write a loop to realize the above code for all pairs of e and phi. I have tried my best to write a loop as follows. But I am quite sure there are multiple problems in it.  Could anyone help me make the loop work?  I know the question may be not very specific. But I have tried my best to find the possible solution from previous threads and it seems no enough information allows me to solve the problem on my own. If you could give me any hint, I would be very grateful.

The following is my attempted codes for the loop.

```
capture program drop solveprogram   
program define solveprogram
    args num var_e var_phi 

    mata: mywork("`num'", "`var_e'", "`var_phi'")

    replace z1=M[1,1] if id==`num'
    replace z2=M[2,1] if id==`num'
    replace z3=M[3,1] if id==`num' 

    replace b1=(e*0.05/(1-0.2)*20000-z1)/50 if id==`num'
    replace b2=(e*0.05/(1-0.2)*9000-z2)/50 if id==`num'
    replace b3=(e*0.05/(1-0.25)*35000-z3)/500 if id==`num'

    replace error_code=ERR[1,1] if id==`num' 
end

clear mata
mata:

void mywork(string scalar num_value, string scalar e_name, string scalar phi_name)
{

    real scalar e_temp, phi_temp

    e_temp = st_data(num_value, e_name)
    phi_temp = st_data(num_value, phi_name)


    S = solvenl_init()
    solvenl_init_argument(S, 1, e_temp)
    solvenl_init_argument(S, 2, phi_temp)
    solvenl_init_evaluator(S, &solvez())
    solvenl_init_type(S, "zero")
    solvenl_init_technique(S, "newton")
    solvenl_init_startingvals(S, J(3,1,10))  
    solvenl_init_conv_maxiter(S, 100)    
    solvenl_init_iter_log(S, "off")
    _solvenl_solve(S)
    ERR=solvenl_result_error_code(S)
    M=solvenl_result_values(S)
    st_matrix("M", M)
    st_matrix("ERR", ERR) 

}

void function solvez(real colvector z, real scalar e, real scalar phi, real colvector y)
{ 

    y[1] = ((20000+z[1])*(1-0.2)/(1+1/e))*(1-(20000/(20000+z[1]))^(1+1/e))-phi-z[1]*(1-0.25)
    y[2] = ((9000+z[2])*(1-0.2)/(1+1/e))*(1-(9000/(9000+z[2]))^(1+1/e))-phi-z[2]*(1-0.25)
    y[3] = ((35000+z[3])*(1-0.25)/(1+1/e))*(1-(35000/(35000+z[3]))^(1+1/e))-phi-z[3]*(1-0.3)

}

end


forvalues i= 1/20000 {
    solveprogram `i' e phi
}
```

Comment: My problem is solved. The main change is to rewrite void function solvez(real colvector z, real scalar e, real scalar phi, real colvector y)  as void function solvez(real colvector z, real colvector y, real scalar e, real scalar phi).

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/mata/1336187-looping-with-mata-function